# FileWriter and computing 12-hour based time in java?

Tags: java, filewriter

I was asked to write a program that will input the employee's id number, time in and time out. The data would be written in a .txt file. I understand that im supposed to use FileWriter but might I ask if its possible to tab the information? Id like to make my .txt file something like this:

```
Name     Time in     Time out     Total hours worked     Salary
Name1    08:00       05:00        9                      4000
Name2    09:00       04:00        7                      3000
```

Also, how would i compute the total hours worked in a 12 hour basis?
Here is my source code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class AYANYAN
{static String ans ;
static int empNumber ;
static String timeIn, timeOut;
static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
static String name[] = { "Ayan Ramirez", "Jenifer Sumbi", "Gen Estrada" , "Tugba Cakir", "Lennox Schatje Huisden"};


public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter("EmpData.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < name.length; i++)
    {
        fWriter.write(name[i] + "\n");
    }
    fWriter.close();

    start () ;

}

public static void control ()
{
    System.out.print ("\n\nPlease select one of the following: \nA. Sign Off\nB. Enter Time in\nC. Enter Time out\nD. Exit Program\n") ;
    ans = s.next() ;

    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("A")){
        signOff () ;
    } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
        timeIn () ;
    } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
        timeOut () ;
    } else if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("D")){
        System.out.print ("\nBYE!\n\n\nProgram made by: Ayan Ramirez\n") ;
    } else {
        System.out.print ("ERROR!") ;
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

public static void start ()
{
    System.out.print ("Please enter your id number: ") ;
        empNumber = s.nextInt();

        if (empNumber == 12345){
        System.out.print ("\nSigned in as: " + name[0]);
        control() ;

        } else if (empNumber == 12346){
        System.out.print ("\nSigned in as: " + name[1]);
        control() ;

        }else if (empNumber == 12347){
        System.out.print ("\nSigned in as: " + name[2]);
        control() ;

        }else if (empNumber == 12348){
        System.out.print ("\nSigned in as: " + name[3]);
        control() ;

        } else if (empNumber == 12349){
        System.out.print ("\nSigned in as: " + name[4]);
        control() ;

        }
        else {
        System.out.print ("\nNTRUDER ALERT!\n\nPLEASE ENTER THE CORRECT ID NUMBER!") ;
        start () ;
        }
}

public static void signOff ()
{
    System.out.print ("Signing off...\n") ;
    start () ;
}

public static String timeIn ()
{
    System.out.print ("Please enter time in: ") ;
    timeIn = s.next () ;
    control () ;

    return (timeIn) ;
}

public static String timeOut ()
{
    System.out.print ("Please enter time out: ") ;
    timeOut = s.next () ;
    control () ;

    return (timeOut) ;
}
}
```

Comment: There are a number of things wrong with the flow of this program. Try following what the program does: start at the `main` method, then follow the flow of the program step by step and think about if it's doing what you think it should be doing.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to produce this kind of output is to use [`String.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) - its [format string syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) supports padding as well as date and time formatting.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to tabbing your information, what exactly do you mean by that?
Do you mean to print a white space which is the same as if you pressed the `tab` button on your keyboard, or do you mean to allow a program such as excel to be able to display items in colums?

For the first one, if you print something like this: `str1 + "\t" + str2`, this will cause a white space to be placed between `str1` and `str2`, just as if you pressed the `tab` key on your keyboard.

If it is the second option, you would nee to enter a delimiter, such as a `;` to allow a program such as excel to split them for you, so you will need to do something like this: `str1 + ";" + str2`.

For the second question, you can take a look at the [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class. You can do something like so:

`K:mm a`

This should print the time in AM/PM format.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\t` as a tabulation char in Java. A slightly better option is the following: you can just determine the length of the current part of the string by `int n = s.length()` and append a number of spaces to it to get a fixed string length `m`. This gives you more freedom on the width than \t, and for varying string length you'd need this anyway.

Sample code:

```
public String tab(String s, int m) {
    int n = s.length();
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i=n; i<m; i++) sb.append(" ");
    return s+sb.toString();
}
```